# passing ruby on rails variables to javascript function via html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
<table id = "mytable">
   <tbody>
        <% @event.each do |event| %>
           <!-- call javascript function here -->
         do_stuff ( <%= event %>)
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result is:

```
do_stuff(#<Event:0x1118119d> do_stuff(#<Event:0x432c632f> do_stuff(#<Event:0x1723c51d> do_stuff(#<Event:0x2d61fec9> do_stuff(#<Event:0x7c9e5565> do_stuff(#<Event:0x7ef899cd> do_stuff(#<Event:0x7339a2da>
```

What is the correct syntax to call the javascript function do_stuff?

Comment: What argument you want to pass to `do_staff`?

Comment: do_stuff is a method or what..?

Comment: I want to pass each ruby on rails "event" into the javascript method, do_stuff, which is a javascript script method. This ought to be easy, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, in fact what's worked best is to create a javascript object, populate it from my ruby object and then call the javascript function I want to run:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      x = new Object();
      x.attr1 = "<%= event.attr1 %>";
      x.attr2 = "<%= event.attr2 %>";

      do_stuff(x);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the javascript in script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">do_stuff('<%= event %>')</script>
```

And be sure that the entire event object is what you want to pass, because the javascript won't know what to do with it. Split it down into whatever event attributes you want to send:

```
<script type="text/javascript">do_stuff('<%= event.attribute1 %>', '<%= event.attribute2 %>')</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest structuring this a little differently. By using something like the [gon gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/gon), you can make the `@event` variable visible to javascript functions. Then, do the whole loop in javascript, so you have less ruby code in your html view. You can loop over the array using plain javascript, or convenience functions from a library like jquery, lodash, or probably any other javascript library you happen to be using.